# Checking Installed programs

Tags: vbscript

I need help in finding installed software version, license etc.

the below script works fine but it lists out all the installed softwares.
But am trying to find out a particular software.It gives nice output, can you help me here.

==================================================

```
'This script outputs to a .tsv file a list of applications installed on the computer
'Output file is software.tsv
'Usage: cscript applications.vbs

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\WINDOWS\system32\temp\software.tsv", True)

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Product")

objTextFile.WriteLine "Caption" & vbtab & _
  "Description" & vbtab & "Identifying Number" & vbtab & _
  "Install Date" & vbtab & "Install Location" & vbtab & _
  "Install State" & vbtab & "Name" & vbtab & _ 
  "Package Cache" & vbtab & "SKU Number" & vbtab & "Vendor" & vbtab _
    & "Version" 

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
  objTextFile.WriteLine objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Description & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallDate2 & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallState & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Name & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.PackageCache & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Vendor & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Version
Next
objTextFile.Close
```

======================================================

i just looking for details of **C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg\hponcfg.exe**  and i do not bother about other installed softwares, by default the above script gives the details of all the softwares, but i just do not need that.
where do i insert this line in the script.??

regards,
Dharanesh,

Comment: Is the software you are looking for listed in the output file?

Answer (score 1):

Check this modification, i tried it with name **Google**, so check it if retruns for you what do you expect or not ?

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
LogFile = "software.tsv"
if objFSO.FileExists(LogFile) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(LogFile)
End if
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(LogFile,8,True)
MySoftware = "Google"
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Product where Name Like " & CommandLineLike(MySoftware))

objTextFile.WriteLine "Caption" & vbtab & _
  "Description" & vbtab & "Identifying Number" & vbtab & _
  "Install Date" & vbtab & "Install Location" & vbtab & _
  "Install State" & vbtab & "Name" & vbtab & _ 
  "Package Cache" & vbtab & "SKU Number" & vbtab & "Vendor" & vbtab _
    & "Version" 

For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
  objTextFile.WriteLine objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Description & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallDate2 & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.InstallState & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Name & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.PackageCache & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Vendor & vbtab & _
  objSoftware.Version
Next
objTextFile.Close
ws.run "Notepad software.tsv"
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(MySoftware)   
    MySoftware = Replace(MySoftware, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & MySoftware & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to get the extended information of a file ?**

For example this vbscript can get the extended information of **Firefox.exe** :

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,ws,RootFolder,LogFile,stFolder,stFile,oShell,oFolder,oFile,i
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
If fso.FileExists(LogFile) Then
    fso.DeleteFile(LogFile)
End If
stFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox")  
stFile ="firefox.exe"  
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace(stFolder) 
Set oFile = oFolder.Items.Item(stFile) 
'Displays extended file properties
For i = 0 to 34 
 WriteLog("[" & i &  "] " & oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFolder.Items, i  ) & " : " & oFolder.GetDetailsOf(oFile, i))
Next
ws.run DblQuote(LogFile)
'*********************************************************************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText)
    Dim fs,ts,LogFile
    Const ForAppending = 8
    LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(LogFile,ForAppending,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************************************
```

Or if you want to check the version of Firefox installed and if it is uptodate or not try this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Const  ForWriting = 2
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT  = &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER  = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS         = &H80000003
Const REG_SZ        = 1
Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
Const REG_BINARY    = 3
Const REG_DWORD     = 4
Const REG_MULTI_SZ  = 7
Dim RC , sPath, sNames, iTypes, sValue, objRegistry
Dim ROOT, i, j , msg, sKey, RC1, sKeyNames, fso, Fich
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Fich = fso.OpenTextFile("Version.txt", ForWriting, true)
Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
sPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
ROOT = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Dim OK
OK = False
Set objRegistry = GetObject("WinMgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")
RC1 = objRegistry.EnumKey(ROOT, sPath, sKeyNames)
If (RC1 = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) And Not IsEmpty(sKeyNames) Then
    For j = LBound(sKeyNames) To UBound(sKeyNames)
        RC = objRegistry.EnumValues(ROOT, sPath & sKeyNames(j), sNames, iTypes)
        If (RC = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) And IsArray(sNames) Then
            If VerifTypes(ROOT, sPath & sKeyNames(j), iTypes) And OK Then Fich.WriteLine vbNewLine & sKeyNames(j) & " : "
            For i = LBound(iTypes) To UBound(iTypes)
                If iTypes(i) = REG_SZ Then
                    RC = objRegistry.GetStringValue(ROOT , sPath & sKeyNames(J), sNames(i), sValue)
                    If (LCase(sNames(i)) = "displayname" And sValue <> "")  Or (LCase(sNames(i)) = "displayversion" And sValue <> "") Then 
                        If InStr(1,LCase(sValue),"firefox") > 0 Then
                            msg = msg & sNames(i) & " = " & sValue
                            OK = True
                            MsgBox sValue & VbcrLf & "La version installée du soft Firefox est : "& ExtractVersion(sValue),64,"La Version installée du Soft Firefox"
                            Dim MyVer,NetVersion,URL,ws
                            MyVer = ExtractVersion(sValue)
                            URL = "http://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/new/"
                            NetVersion = GetFirefoxMajorVersion(URL)
                            msgbox NetVersion
                            If CompareVersions(MyVer,NetVersion) = -1 Then
                                MsgBox "La dernière version de Firefox est : " & NetVersion & VbCrlf &_
                                "Il y a une mise à jour en ligne !",48,"Il y a une mise à jour en ligne ! "
                                set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                                ws.run URL
                            Else
                                MsgBox "Firefox est à jour !",64,"Firefox est à jour !"
                            end if
                            Fich.Write msg & vbNewLine & "La version installée du soft Firefox est : "& ExtractVersion(sValue) & vbNewLine
                        End If  
                    End If
                    OK = False
                End If
                msg = ""
            Next ' pour i
'MsgBox msg
        Else
            'Msgbox "L'erreur suivante est survenue : " & Err.Description
        End If
    Next ' pour J
    Fich.Close
End If
Shell.run "version.txt"
'******************************************************************************************************************
Function Lsh(ByVal N, ByVal Bits)
    Lsh = N * (2 ^ Bits)
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Function VerifTypes(ROOT, strPath, Types)
' Cette fonction vérifie si la clé (strPath) contient des valeurs 
' "DisplayVersion" ou "DisplayName" et qui ne sont pas être vides
' pour ne pas retourner celles qui n'en contiennent pas.
    Dim Ret, strNames, Verif, ind
    Verif = False
    Ret = objRegistry.EnumValues(ROOT, strPath,strNames, Types)
    If (Ret = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) And IsArray(strNames) Then
        For ind = LBound(strNames) To UBound(strNames)
            If LCase(strNames(ind)) = "displayname" Or LCase(strNames(ind)) = "displayversion" Then
                Verif = True
                Exit For
            ELse 
                Verif = False
                End If
            Next
        End If  
        VerifTypes = Verif
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Function ExtractVersion(Data) 
        Dim objRegex,Match,Matches
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\d{2}\.\d"
        objRegex.Global = False
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            ExtractVersion = Match.Value
        Next
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Function GetVersionStringAsArray(ByVal Version)
        Dim VersionAll, VersionParts, N
        VersionAll = Array(0, 0, 0, 0)
        VersionParts = Split(Version, ".")
        For N = 0 To UBound(VersionParts)
            VersionAll(N) = CLng(VersionParts(N))
        Next
        Dim Hi, Lo
        Hi = Lsh(VersionAll(0), 16) + VersionAll(1)
        Lo = Lsh(VersionAll(2), 16) + VersionAll(3)

        GetVersionStringAsArray = Array(Hi, Lo)
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
' Compares two versions "a.b.c.d". If Version1 < Version2,
' returns -1. If Version1 = Version2, returns 0.
' If Version1 > Version2, returns 1.
Function CompareVersions(ByVal Version1, ByVal Version2)
        Dim Ver1, Ver2, Result
        Ver1 = GetVersionStringAsArray(Version1)
        Ver2 = GetVersionStringAsArray(Version2)
        If Ver1(0) < Ver2(0) Then
            Result = -1
        ElseIf Ver1(0) = Ver2(0) Then
            If Ver1(1) < Ver2(1) Then
                Result = -1
            ElseIf Ver1(1) = Ver2(1) Then
                Result = 0
            Else
                Result = 1
            End If
        Else
            Result = 1
        End If
        CompareVersions = Result
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Function GetFirefoxMajorVersion(URL)
        Dim Titre,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches
        Titre = "La dernière version de Firefox"
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ie.Navigate(URL)
        ie.Visible=False
        DO WHILE ie.busy
            Wscript.Sleep 100
        Loop
        Data = ie.document.documentElement.innerHTML
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\d{2}\.\d"
        objRegex.Global = True
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            GetFirefoxMajorVersion = Match.Value
        Next
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
```

**Here is another way to get FileVersion of Firefox.exe using Powershell and Vbscript**

**GetFileDetailsFirefox.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyCmd,Ws,Ret,ByPassPSFile,PSFile,PathFile,OutPut
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
PathFile = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%") & "\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"
OutPut = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%") & "\firefox_version.txt"
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /c PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
MyCmd = "Get-ChildItem "& DblQuote(PathFile) &" | Get-ItemProperty | Select VersionInfo | Format-List > " & OutPut &""
Call WriteLog(MyCmd)
Ret = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
ws.run DblQuote(OutPut)
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteLog(strText)
Dim fs,ts,PSFile
Const ForWriting = 2
    PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I think above script is bit confusing. So if can modify my script please.